# lambda arguments unpack error

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, tuples, unpack

In Python 2 this code is OK:

```
f = lambda (m, k): m + k

m = [1,2,3,4]
k = [5,6,7,8]

print(map(f, zip(m, k)))
```

but in Python 3 the following error occurred:

```
f = lambda (m, k): m + k
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I remove parentheses in lambda expression then another error occurred:

```
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'k'
```

Also approach with tuple as single lambda argument works in Python 3, but it's not clear (hard for reading):

```
f = lambda args: args[0] + args[1]
```

How can I unpack values in the right way in Python 3?

Comment: `map()` applies `f` to each element of the provided iterable; in your given example, `map()` tries to pass `(1, 5)` into your function, which takes two arguments, but only one is provided, so it fails and gives you the error.

Comment: They removed it from functions, to play nicely with type hints (among others). See also my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54991720/1338797

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The removal of tuple unpacking is discussed in [PEP 3113](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/). Basically, you can't do this in Python 3. Under the headline *[Transition plan](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/#transition-plan)*, you see that the "suggested" way of doing this is as your final code block:

```
lambda x_y: x_y[0] + x_y[1]
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the same syntax in both Python 2 and Python 3 if you use [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) instead of `map` which unpacks the tuple items for us:

```
>>> from itertools import starmap
>>> f = lambda m, k: m + k
>>> list(starmap(f, zip(m, k)))
[6, 8, 10, 12]
```

Answer (score 8):

You may find this solution easier to read:

```
lambda mk: (lambda m,k: m + k)(*mk)
```

Additionally, I'd argue that the unpacking makes this more (1) Pythonic and (2) consistent with the manual unpacking of tuple arguments for *named* functions, required in Python 3 by [PEP 3113](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/).

Comment: Very nice, although a bit intricate (is it a synonym for "pythonic", BTW?). THIS approach will win hands down for more than 2-tuples! Indices **are** bad. Just think: `lambda abcdef: abcdef[0] + abcdef[2] - abcdef[1] // abcdef[4]`?

Comment: This a natural _functional programming_ workaround to the scenario at hand, for those into functional programming. I just wonder how does the the extra function wrapping escape the original limitation prior to going down the rabbit hole in the PEP.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use parentheses in Python3 to unpack arguments in lambda functions ([PEP 3113](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/)), Try:

```
f = lambda m, k: m + k
```

---

To make it work with your code, you should use:

```
lambda mk: mk[0] + mk[1]
```

Comment: Is it work with map(f, zip(m, k))? As for (I've wrote) TypeError occurred.

Comment: @Alexei Then you should try `lambda mk: mk[0] + mk[1]`. I didn't look at the rest of your code before I posted the answer :)

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I think it's some strange decision in Python evolution...

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just sum() to add numbers without unpack:

```
f = lambda args: sum(args)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer =) But that was just simple example. In really my lambda more complicated. Moreover I think just sum function can be used without being wrapped in lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
map(f, m, k)
```

Note that `f` can be

```
from operator import add
map(add, m, k)
```