# Most pythonic way to port this tuple unpacking with lambda from Python 2 into Python 3

Tags: python, lambda

I have the following Python 2 code which unpacks a tuple inside a lambda. This lambda is contained inside a for loop.

```
    for lab, lab_pred, length in zip(labels, labels_pred, sequence_lengths):
        accs += map(lambda (a, b): a == b, zip(lab, lab_pred))
```

What is the best way to port this into Python 3?

Comment: Apart from the lack of tuple unpacking in Python 3 function args, you have another issue: `map` in Python 3 returns an iterator not a list. That's the case with many functions that return lists in Python 2.

Comment: This is just another case of Python core developers' didactic approach - break things to "teach them" to be more "pythonic" (and make Py2/Py3 interop harder). See my answer for a more general case, not just your specific snippet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best solution would be to not use `map` and `lambda`, use a list comprehension instead:

```
accs += [a == b for a, b in zip(lab, lab_pred)]
```

Comment: Definitely! Using a lambda with `map` or `filter` is a bit silly because it means you're calling a function on every item just to execute the expression in the lambda, whereas with the list comp (or gen exp) you execute the expression directly. Python function calls have a lot more overhead than C function calls, so it's good to avoid them when you don't need them.

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer functional style there is:

```
from operator import eq
from itertools import starmap

accs.extend(starmap(eq, zip(lab, lab_pred)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an intentional regression in Python3 (although I don't know the rationale - if you happen to - please comment below) in order to discourage `lambda` and in the long run - using Python2 altogether.

## Pythonic quick fix

(edited, previous idea didn't really work)
See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47947955/1338797

If your lambda is flat, there is an upgrade path to Python3:

```
lambda (x, y): x + y
```

becomes

```
lambda xy: (lambda x, y: x + y)(*xy)
```

Nice, but it has 2 downsides:

1. Welcome to Lisp ;) It's intricate (but pythonic, like `str.join`)
2. It won't cut nested tuples like: `lambda ((x0, y0), (x1, y1)): abs(x1-x0) + abs(y1-y0)`
3. An extra lambda.

## Why are they forcing us to use small `def` functions?

Lambdas are bad for a couple of reasons (about 3-4 may be valid):

1. Just because: `lambda` is broken in Python. It's "pythonic" to know this.
2. Lambdas (in Python, not in some other language! I won't repeat this disclaimer in the following points) can only handle single expressions.
3. Lambdas have no `__name__`s.
4. Lambdas have ugly `__repr__`esentations.
5. Lambdas <s>are</s> *can make code* slow. (when often created unnecessarily)
6. Lambdas are slow. (to run, compared to competing constructs)

(5 & 6 are relevant only in most performance-critical code anyway).

Small functions in Python are recommended, and they think it's no problem, because it only takes 2 lines more. (2 instead of 0, because a lambda can be inline). Thus `lambda x, y: x == y` becomes:

```
def are_equal(x, y):
    return x == y
```

(forget `operator.eq` here, not every lambda will have it's equivalent in this module anyway).

Actually, if you stick to PEP-8, this function takes 4 extra lines in local scope, and 6 extra lines in global scope, including empty line padding.

## Example situation: how to keep compatibility

Suppose you have a list, or other iterable of tuples. You want to get a max value using `max(..., key=...)`. After that, you can directly unpack the tuple. In the days of Python2 it would be:

```
x, y, w, h = max(faces, key=lambda (x, y, w, h): w * h)
```

(Again, you could lecture me here about the superiority of `typing.Namedtuple`s, `dataclasses`, or `@attr.s`, but right now I get a `list` of `tuple`s from OpenCV.

I found the least painful way to be to use a function:

```
def face_area(*args):
    x, y, w, h = args if len(args) == 4 else args[0]
    return w * h

 x, y, w, h = max(faces, key=face_area)
```

Python2 will get a nested tuple in `args`, and Python3 will get a tuple of length 4. You can unpack it manually as above, and then proceed with `return`ing your result.

Some would say, it gives the code an occasion to become more self-documented, because I've had to think of a name for the `key` function.

Comment: Just for reference - see the rationale: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/ - To sum it up: "we'll remove it, because it will be convenient and nobody *I* know uses it."